# Create table with calculations from two tables. Python. Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data1 = [[1, 2000], [2, 3000]]
df_players = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['cluster', 'users'])
df_players
```

| cluster | users |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 |
| 2 | 3000 |

```
data2 = [[1, 2], [2, 4]]
df_multiplyer = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['cluster', 'multiplyer'])
df_multiplyer
```

| cluster | multiplyer |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |

And I have an array

```
coef = np.arange(.05, 0.16, 0.05)
coef
```

0.05

0.1

0.15

A want to create the table as shown below with calculated field `users*myltiplyer*coeff`

Desired output:

| cluster | num_users | multiplyer | coeffs | calculated_field |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 | 0.05 | 200 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 | 0.1 | 400 |
| 1 | 2000 | 2 | 0.15 | 600 |
| 2 | 3000 | 4 | 0.05 | 600 |
| 2 | 3000 | 4 | 0.1 | 1200 |
| 2 | 3000 | 4 | 0.15 | 1800 |

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create helper DataFrame, then use `merge` by `cluster` and then cross join by new `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'coeffs':coef, 'a':1})
df = (df_players.merge(df_multiplyer, on='cluster')
                .assign(a = 1)
                .merge(df1, on='a')
                .drop('a', axis=1))
df['calculated_field'] = df[['users','multiplyer','coeffs']].prod(axis=1)
print (df)
   cluster  users  multiplyer  coeffs  calculated_field
0        1   2000           2    0.05             200.0
1        1   2000           2    0.10             400.0
2        1   2000           2    0.15             600.0
3        2   3000           4    0.05             600.0
4        2   3000           4    0.10            1200.0
5        2   3000           4    0.15            1800.0
```

Comment: Thanks for answer) I have a problem with this piece of code .merge(pd.DataFrame({'coeffs':coef}), how='cross')). It gives me No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False

Comment: @Smasell - What is problem?

Comment: I think it's because of version of pandas(my version is 1.1.5) at work. Unfortunately I can't update this version so I need to find another code to do this(

Comment: anyway your code is absolutly correct. Thx you)

Comment: @Smasell - Can you test now?